# how to rename a joomla component?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I want to change the component name build by me , i have tried changing the xml file but it does not help also tried changing the component name through datbase but same result .can anybody help me in this ?

any help would be appriciated .
thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but there's a lot involved in renaming a component if you want to do it properly, you have to change the class names, folder name, the xml.. etc.. you also would need to edit the database OR uninstall and re install it once you've made all of your changes.

The same applies to modules, plugins and templates.. though those tend to be a little easier..

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you need to change it in the database, AS WELL AS in the xml, AS WELL AS you need to change the directory and file names to match the new component's name.

Answer (score 0):

Using PhpMyAdmin go to the MySQL database table named jos_components and browse the data. Find the component name under Field you want to change... edit & save the entry.